# \uline and German quotation marks

Tags: errors, ulem, german

I'm using the `\uline` command from the `ulem` package. But unfortunately it causes an error when used togehter with German quotation marks (`\glqq`,`\grqq`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
{\glqq}These are German quotation marks.{\grqq}\\
\uline{This is an underlined sentence.}\\
%\uline{{\glqq}But both of them together do not work.{\grqq}} 
\end{document}
```

I commented out the last line. It causes an error and I don't know why. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Is it an option to put the quotation marks outside of the \uline{} command, like so?

`{\glqq}\uline{But both of them together do not work.}{\qrqq}`

Comment: Hide them in an `\mbox{}`

Comment: @MathewCarrick: This would not underline the quotation marks then (underlining **and** quotation does not look very nice, in combination, however)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\mbox` can protect the special quotation characters. In addition, I used the `csquotes` package for easy change of quotation style, wrapping it into a command called `\afz` (German Anführungszeichen -- quotation marks)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,style=german]{csquotes}

\newcommand{\afz}[1]{\enquote{#1}}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\afz{These are German quotation marks.}

\uline{This is an underlined sentence.}

\uline{\mbox{\afz{But now all together it works.}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the nice comments by Ulrike I should point that `\mbox` prevents line breaking, thereby destroying an important feature of the `ulem` package.

Comment: If you put the whole sentence in an mbox, there no line break is possible.

Comment: That's true, but is that an issue so far?

Comment: Could be. After all the OP could simply use `\underline` if line breaks don't matter. So you should imho mention that you are disabling the main feature of `\uline`.